# ASP .NET Core 3 - Setup Identity Results in Errors

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

I am trying to setup a new asp .net core 3 project.  I am trying to asp .net identity into it.  When I attempt to create a database migration, I get the following error;

An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: GenericArguments[0], 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser', on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`6[TUser,TContext,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserLogin,TUserToken]' violates the constraint of type 'TUser'.

I've spent all afternoon trying to figure this out, but I can't figure out what this means, or more importantly, how to fix it.

My program class looks like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

My Startup.cs file looks like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<McClureDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<McClureDbContext>();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings.
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

            // Lockout settings.
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // User settings.
            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

My DbContext Class looks like this:

```
public class McClureDbContext : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>
{
    public McClureDbContext()
    {
    }
    public McClureDbContext(DbContextOptions<McClureDbContext> options): base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Home> Homes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<HomePicture> HomePictures { get; set; }
    public DbSet<HomeVideo> HomeVideos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Province> Province { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Country> Country { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        var Configuration = builder.Build();
        var connString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connString, options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure());
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<Home>().Property(n => n.Sold).HasDefaultValue(false);
    }
}
```

My three data types (for the moment), look like this:

```
public class Home
{
    public Home()
    {
    }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int32 HomeId { get; set; }
    public Guid AspNetUsersId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AspNetUsersId")]
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string City { get; set; }
    public Int64 ProvinceId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProvinceId")]
    public Province Province { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public double? Latitude { get; set; }
    public double? Longitude { get; set; }
    public bool Sold { get; set; }
    public ICollection<HomeVideo> HomeVideos { get; set; }
    public ICollection<HomePicture> HomePictures { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime DateEntered { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
}
public class HomeVideo
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int32 HomeVideoId { get; set; }
    public Int32 HomeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("HomeId")]
    public Home Home { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(1024)]
    public string VideoUrl { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime DateEntered { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
}
public class HomePicture
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int32 HomePictureId { get; set; }
    public Int32 HomeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("HomeId")]
    public Home Home { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(1024)]
    public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime DateEntered { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

I don't remember having any of these types of issues when I built stuff in asp .net core 2.x.  I figure that I am doing something wrong, but have no idea how to fix it.  Searching google has not been much help today.  I am at a loss.  Any ideas/directions are appreciated.

TIA,
Wally

Comment: After much fiddling around and looking at things, I found the issue.  the issue was that I had the IdentityUser type in the AddDefaultEntity call.  I should have been using my ApplicationUser as my datatype.  It took me a long time to see this.  Hopefully this helps somebody else not waste the better part of a day trying to figure this out.  :-)